# Error: "Creating the deployment 'xx-20221221-071859-a2d8' would exceed the quota of '800

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

We use Azure DevOps YAML pipeline for managed group scoped deployments. In the first stage we validate the ARM deployment via YAML task AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 (validation mode). Since today it fails with the following error: Template validation failed. Error: "Creating the deployment 'xxx-20221221-071859-a2d8' would exceed the quota of '800'. The current deployment count is '800'. Please delete some deployments before creating a new one, or see https://aka.ms/800LimitFix for information on managing deployment limits.

The YAML code snippet:

```
    - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
      displayName: Validate ARM Template
      inputs:
        azureResourceManagerConnection: ${{ variables.TestAzureResourceManagerConnection }}
        deploymentScope: 'Management Group'
        location: $(location)
        templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
        csmFile: '${{ variables.MainTemplateFilePath }}'
        overrideParameters: '-parTargetManagementGroupID $(managementGroupID)'
        deploymentMode: 'Validation'
```

I already checked the deployments in the corresponding managementgroup and other managementgroups and deleted them without any success.